# How to pass arguments when inheriting prototypes JS?

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

For example, we have a function

```
function FirstFunction(name, surname){
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    ...
}
```

We have some functions in its prototype and we have another function "SecondFunction" with it's own prototype. When I want to inherit prototypes I write

```
SecondFunction.prototype = Object.create(FirstFunction.prototype);
```

Now, when I try to create new variable with

```
var newVariable = new SecondFunction();
```

I want to pass arguments 'name' and 'surname' that are listed in the FirstFunction to be able to use functions in the FirstFunction's prototype. Which is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the right way to do it is using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) :

```js
function FirstFunction(name, surname){
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
}

function SecondFunction(name, surname) {
  FirstFunction.call(this, name, surname)
}
SecondFunction.prototype = Object.create(FirstFunction.prototype);


var newVariable = new SecondFunction('Harry', 'Potter');
console.log(newVariable);
```

You can refer to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance#Defining_a_Teacher()_constructor_function) that explains it.

Comment: An `.apply(this, arguments)` will pass any amount of variables, so even if `FirstFunction` now accepts a third one called `age`, then you don't need to change `SecondFunction` to accommodate it.

Comment: @VLAZ If the parent constructor change its interface, there's a good change you will need to change the child class anyway